# How to use iterator_category to indicate the tag of a customized iterator class?

Tags: c++

As titled, the following code snippet doesn't work even I defined the type "iterator_category" and made it visible to the outside in the class definition, the expectation of the output should be '1' rather than '0'. How should I fix that?

```
struct Iter {
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << std::__has_iterator_typedefs<Iter>::value << std::endl;  // output '0';
  // std::cout << (typeid(std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category) == typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterator_category` is not the only member type that a standard library compatible iterator should provide. If you take look at how `__has_iterator_typedefs` is [implemented](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/iterator#L444), you'll see that it also checks for the presence of these member types: `difference_type`, `value_type`, `reference`, and `pointer`. Add all these, and then `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category` will return the category of your iterator.

```
struct Iter {
  using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
  using value_type        = int;
  using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using reference         = value_type&;
  using pointer           = value_type*;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category, 
                             std::random_access_iterator_tag>);
```